# How can I get help with edits for my closed question

Tags: support

My question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355700/cli-method-to-find-all-nested-jar-files-containing-the-log4j-library) was closed yesterday. I edited and resubmitted and my edits were apparently rejected. There is no detail given and no way to see who is rejecting my question. Is there a way to ask whoever keeps rejecting my question for more detail?

My question is more specific than many others I see so I don't know what is required.

Comment: The close reason is: *"We don’t allow questions about general computing hardware and software on Stack Overflow."* - People can't see what about your question is about programming.

Comment: @Nick thanks for responding! is there a better Stack Exchange community than SO for specific command line filesystem search questions like this?

Comment: Potentially Super User, although I'm not active there and nor do I know the rules well, so I'd suggest reading their asking guidance or wait for someone who is more active there to weigh in on it here.

Comment: I have learned here that doing repeated edits to my question was bad. I should have had more detail ready when i first posted. In this case I believe I should have posted a new question instead of trying to clarify my original question. The first answers showed me that the wording of my question title was ambiguous.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To add to [Nick](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3270037/nick)'s point, [The Super User platform](https://superuser.com) would be a good platform for you to use in this instance, and its rules can be found here: https://superuser.com/help/asking

Comment: This may be a good suggestion, but it's *generally* advisable to only direct users to other sites on the network if you're active on that site yourself.

Comment: Ok sorry, won't do it again :)

Comment: It's fine. The recommendation seems reasonable (not that I'm at all active there myself), and you *did* link to the help pages as well. It's just a suggestion for the future. Some sites in particular *really* don't like it if you send an off-topic question to that site, so it's better to be conservative with such suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately the question was simply resubmitted to Super User as it was originally written. It was actually pretty bad advice to suggest Super User, with the question in it's current form, simply not enough details.  **Yes;** I am very active within the Super User community.  I keep my communities hidden for a reason.

Comment: No - it was not simply resubmitted the same way as it was written. I edited to try to make it more specific given what i learned while trying to post on SO. I think Super User is a good place to try this now. I plan to update the question as I try things to find a solution.